# Why is a Dynkin System closed under the set theoretic difference?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a Dynkin System and $A,B \in \mathcal{D}$ with $B \subseteq A$. Then $A \backslash B \in D $.

Why is that? I see that :

$$ A \backslash B = A \cap B^c = (A^c \cup B)^c $$

So now I could either show that $(A^c \cup B) \in \mathcal{D}$ or $(A^c \cup B)^c \in  \mathcal{D}$ to prove it, but I can't seem how either of these statements has to be true.

Comment: Could you write down the definition of a Dynkin System that you are using?

Comment: Since $B\subset A$, $A^{c}\cap B=\emptyset$ and so by the definition of Dynkin System (which I can only speculate as you didn't give one) $A^{c}\cup B$ is in $\mathcal{D}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Wikipedia there are two definitions of a Dynkin System. In one it is axiomatic that if $B\subseteq A$ then $A\backslash B\in \mathcal D$.

In the other we have that if $A\in\mathcal D$ then $A^c\in\mathcal D$ and as $\Omega\in\mathcal D,$ we have $\varnothing \in \mathcal D.$ Finally if $A_1,A_2,\dots\in\mathcal D$ and $A_i\cap A_j=\varnothing$ for each $i$ and $j$ then $\bigcup_i A_i\in\mathcal D.$

So to prove your last step we need to show $A^c\cup B\in \mathcal D.$

So set $A_1=A^c,\;A_2=B,$ and $A_i=\varnothing$ for $i>2.$ now $A^c\cap B=\varnothing$ as $B\subseteq A$ so by the above definition $A^c\cup B\cup\varnothing\cup\cdots=A^c\cup B\in \mathcal D.$

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I only knew of the definition where $A \in D \implies A^c \in D$. This is the answer I was looking for